# Wrong Record count with uniqueidentifier and casting to nvarchar in TSQL for xml path

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, count, for-xml-path

Here are some sample records

```
ID(UniqueIdentifier)                 UserId title   description version     parentid    
8362AB94-946F-4092-97C2-ABD957CC2E20    3   title   desc    0   0   
C4E3FCC1-49B5-4310-931F-B8EE48B3F38E    3   title2  desc2   0   1           8362AB94-946F-4092-97C2-ABD957CC2E20
C622113B-C6E6-4ED1-B727-E4F864643CD2    3   title3  desc3   0   2           8362AB94-946F-4092-97C2-ABD957CC2E20
```

Records represent a hierarchical edits of textual data. Such as , on saving a edit of ParentBoard a new entry is made and with incremental version number i.e `1`,`2`(this all happens on application).
The columns of interest here are

```
ID - Unique Identifier

ParentId - NVARCHAR(50)
```

I am trying to build a xml as follows

```
<Edits>
  <Id>314BA459-3749-4BC1-8AA4-E72B882539F5</Id>
  <Title>Parent Title</Title>
  <Description>Parent Description</Description>
  <Version>0</Version>
  <ParentId></ParentId>
  <SubBoardCount>2</SubBoardCount>
</Edits>
```

#### Query

```
SELECT
            Id  'Id',
            Title   'Title',
            [Description]   'Description',
            Version     'Version',
            ParentId    'ParentId',
            (select COUNT(*) WHERE ParentId =  (CAST(Id AS NVARCHAR(50)))) 'SubBoardCount',
    FROM    Edits
    WHERE ParentId IS NULL OR ParentId = ''
    FOR XML PATH('Edits')
```

#### Problem

Why do i always end up getting `SubBoardCount as 0` rather than 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because your "subquery" isn't searching the table. Perhaps you meant:

```
SELECT
    Id 'Id',
    Title 'Title',
    [Description] 'Description',
    Version 'Version',
    ParentId 'ParentId',
    (SELECT COUNT(*) 
     FROM Edits e2 
     WHERE e2.ParentId =  (CAST(e1.Id AS NVARCHAR(50)))) 'SubBoardCount',
FROM    
    Edits e1
WHERE 
    ParentId IS NULL OR ParentId = ''
FOR XML PATH('Edits')
```

Without the extra `FROM Edits e2` clause, the references to `ParentId` and `Id` within the subquery were referencing those column values from `e1` (as I've now aliased it) and these aren't ever equal.

Comment: +1 Perfectly Put there. will mark as answer.btw isn't it implicit in the `count` that table referred is `Edits` that's what i thought